# Deduping a StringBuilder List of Items in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I need to dedupe a list of columns in a SQL select statement that is being generated with a StringBuilder. I need to return a StringBuilder object as well.

The solution I came up with *works* but it looks like a dang nightmare. Can someone suggest a cleaner way to achieve this?

```
//The SQL statement is being passed to my code as a StringBuilder
//This is just scaffolding to fake that input.
StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
items.Append("SELECT ");
items.Append("Apple,");
items.Append("Carrot,");
items.Append("Pear,");
items.Append("Orange,");
items.Append("Apple");
items.Append(" From fruit_table");
//End scaffolding

//My code start:
//Chop off the non-important parts
items.Replace("SELECT ", "");
items.Replace(" From fruit_table", "");

//Convert string to list, seperating on commas
List<string> itemList = items.ToString().ToUpper().Split(',').ToList<string>();

//Found a handy "distinct" method in LINQ library
itemList = itemList.Distinct().ToList();

//Wipe out the original stringbuilder. For clarity and consistency with some other code, I'd like to reuse the same stringBuilder that was passed to me.
items.Clear();

//Rebuild my stringbuilder, now deduped
items.Append("SELECT ");
itemList.ForEach(x => items.Append(x + ","));
//Remove that comma after last fruit item
items.Remove((items.Length - 1), 1);
items.Append(" FROM fruit_table");

//Not really going to output to console, but you
//get the idea.
Console.WriteLine(items.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Just throwing it out to be sure - there is no way to change the input to your code?

Comment: I know what you mean, but no, not really. If the code above mine is working correctly, there should never be duplicates anyway. I just need to insert my deduping code temporarily until the larger piece is fixed in the next major release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do it without having to hard-code the prefix and suffix elements:

```
// Encapsulate the behavior in an extension method we can run
// directly on a StringBuilder object
public static StringBuilder DeduplicateColumns(this StringBuilder input) {
    // Assume that we can split into large "chunks" on spaces
    var sections = input.ToString().Split(' ');
    var resultSections = new List<string>();

    foreach (var section in sections) {
        var items = section.Split(',');

        // If there aren't any commas, spit this chunk back out
        // Otherwise, split on the commas and get distinct items
        if (items.Count() == 1)
            resultSections.Add(section);
        else
            resultSections.Add(string.Join(",", items.Distinct()));
    }

    return new StringBuilder(string.Join(" ", resultSections));
}
```

Test code:

```
var demoStringBuilder = new StringBuilder
    ("SELECT Apple,Carrot,Pear,Orange,Apple From fruit_table");
var cleanedBuilder = demoStringBuilder.DeduplicateColumns();

// Output: SELECT Apple,Carrot,Pear,Orange From fruit_table
```

Here's a fiddle: [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GzJ45E)

Comment: Thank you Nate, I like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are stuck with starting with the `StringBuilder` then I think you've pretty much worked out what you need to do.

I would make it a little cleaner like this though:

```
var prefix = "SELECT ";
var suffix = " From fruit_table";
var result =
    String.Format("{0}{2}{1}",
        prefix,
        suffix,
        String.Join(",",
            items
                .ToString()
                .Replace(prefix, "")
                .Replace(suffix, "")
                .Split(',')
                .Select(x => x.Trim())
                .Distinct()));
items.Clear();
items.Append(result);
```

Before:

```
SELECT Apple,Carrot,Pear,Orange,Apple From fruit_table
```

After:

```
SELECT Apple,Carrot,Pear,Orange From fruit_table
```

If you know that there are no spaces between the names of the columns, then this is slightly cleaner:

```
var result =
    String.Format("{0}{2}{1}",
        prefix,
        suffix,
        String.Join(",",
            items
                .ToString()
                .Split(' ')[1]
                .Split(',')
                .Distinct()));
```